# Why does an Insecure gRPC server still allow connections from secured clients

Tags: node.js, grpc, google-cloud-run

I can't seem to understand what's happening behind the scene, but any guidance will really be appreciated.

I have the following grpc server that is hosted on Google Cloud Run:

**server.js**

```
        server.bindAsync(`0.0.0.0:${process.env.PORT}`, grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), () => { //Notice, this is insecure
            server.start();
            console.log('GRPC Service Started');
        });
```

Then I was given a service url of the form:
https://test-service-abcdefghij-ue.a.run.app

Then below is a client that connects to the above server using the following code:

**client.js**

```
 ... new test_proto.TestAccount("test-service-abcdefghij-ue.a.run.app", grpc.credentials.createSsl()); //Notice I used createSsl instead of createInsecure()
```

As you can see from my client code, I used `createSsl` without passing a self signed certificate, yet the connection to the `createInsecure` server worked.

I always thought both server and client must provide same self-signed certificates.

So, why does this still work even though the server is configured to be insecure? Does it mean data will still be transmitted in plain text regardless?

Comment: Cloud Run does not support client SSL certificates. The client verifies the server's SSL certificate. I think you are confused about what insecure means for Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, I think I am a bit confused. Lol. So, based on your explanation, does that mean data transmission between client and server is not in plain text since the client verifies the server's ssl certificate on Cloud Run? Or do I need to do more to safely transmit data? The final point been is the above code I shared very safe in production?

Comment: If a client connects to a Cloud Run service using HTTP (insecure), Cloud Run will redirect the client to an HTTPS endpoint. That means the final connection is encrypted with symmetric encryption. However, encryption alone does not mean a connection is secure. Google Cloud Run also supports IAP to authorize a user's access. In other words, a secure connection requires encryption and authorization.

Comment: Wow! very well explained!!! I get it now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments from @John Hanley posting the answer, Cloud Run does not support client SSL certificates. The client verifies the server's SSL certificate. If a client connects to a Cloud Run service using HTTP (insecure), Cloud Run will redirect the client to an HTTPS endpoint. That means the final connection is encrypted with symmetric encryption. However, encryption alone does not mean a connection is secure. Google Cloud Run also supports IAP to authorize a user's access. In other words, a secure connection requires encryption and authorization.
You can have a look at [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run).